# Backtrace relation in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database

I want to get user id with kind of backtrace relation in my Rails application (2 levels above in relation)

My models

User.rb

```
has_many :printers, dependent: :destroy
has_many :orders
```

Printer.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :orders
```

Order.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :printer
has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
```

In my view (/orders/show) for an single Order

```
    Order ID: <%= @order.id %>
    Printer ID: <%= @order.printer_id %>
    Performer ID: <%= ???? %> <!-- I need the owner of the given printer ID above -->
```

Order show action is simple

```
def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id]) #get current order
end
```

So I can also simply get the ID of user, because it was made via (id of person who place the order)

```
@order = current_user.orders.build(order_params)
```

And manupulate with this User, getting any data I need

```
 @order.user.first_name
```

But I have now idea how I can get and ID of the printer owner it this case? Is it possible with my model type or should I refactor everything usuing has_many :through ?

Any reply will be highly appreciated

Schema

```
  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id" # this is an id of user who place the order
    t.integer  "printer_id" #this is and id of printer, which was ordered
  end

  create_table "printers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id" # this is the owner of printer - to which other user pass the order
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what a `through` association is for - though not a simple one.

If your Order didn't have  a user, you could do it quite simply with:

```
class Order
  belongs_to :printer
  has_one :user, :through => :printer
```

But you don't want it to get the user-that-owns-the-printer confused with the user-that-created-the-order so we need to call it something different, but tell rails that it's still a user.

You can try the following, I haven't tested it... you may need to adjust it slightly to get it working, but it should give you the gist of what needs to be done:

```
class Order
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :printer
  has_one :printer_owner, :through => :printer, :class_name => :user, :foreign_key => :user_id
```